# Need explanations about SSL issue and installation process

Tags: openssl, ssl, apache-httpd

I am trying to install SSL on my server.
First of all I wanted to purchase a certificate.
They asked me to generate a CSR file.
I created it and it resulted with two files:

- my.website.key
- my.website.csr

I took the code from the CSR file and pasted it to the CSR field and indeed I received an email from comodo with PositiveSSL Certificate attached to the message body, and four files zipped in the attachment.

the files are:

- my_website.crt
- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
- COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

I managed to enable the SSL module, but in the default-ssl file it requires two files:

```
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

I think I'm supposed to change these to the new files, but I do not have a PEM file nor I do not see where should I use the CRT file - this is where i'm lost. I have 6 files in total, non of them is PEM.

The .key file I assume is the one I created at the first phase?

I hope my question is clear, i'm quite new to Linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this as a guide https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm.

For the `SSLCertificateFile` include the following in the PEM file.

- primary certificate (my_website.crt)
- and the other certificates (can be in the order you enumerated)

For `SSLCertificateKeyFile` use my.website.key the you generated earlier.

Comment: thank you for your answered - I went over many articles but that's all I needed. I'd never guess I need them all.

Answer (score 2):

you convert `.crt` to `.pem` using

```
openssl x509 -in ${CLIENT}.crt -out ${CLIENT}.pem -outform pem
```

you might have to specify key

```
openssl x509 -in ${CLIENT}.crt -inkey ${CLIENT}.key -passin pass:foobarbaz  -out ${CLIENT}.pem -outform pem
```

(assuming foobarbaz is you password)